# Vercel seems to ignore my requirements.txt file so no packages are installed

Tags: python, vercel

I'm running a React frontend with a python serverless backend on Vercel.

My `requirements.txt` file contains the following lines:

```
pydantic==2.4.2
openai~=0.28.1
python-dotenv~=1.0.0
```

And yet, none of these packages are installed upon running.

When hitting that python api endpoint, Vercel does print
`Installing required dependencies...` and completes without errors.
However, the execution is immediately interrupted by an error because `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'`. And yet, this dependency is the 1st one listed on the `requirements.txt` file.

Can anyone help me diagnose what's going on?

Cheers!

P.s. if it helps, here's my file structure:
[image]

Comment: Don't you accidentally have also Pipfile?

Comment: @STerliakov, no... I attached my file tree